# I want to stop Combobox.Items.Clear() from moving my text cursor

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a Winforms application with a combobox with its `DropDownStyle` set to `Simple`.

When I call `this.InputComboBox.Items.Clear()`, it moves the text insertion cursor from wherever it is to the beginning of the input box, although the text contents is unchanged.  Why is this happening, and can I prevent it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using textchanged_eventhandler to search data from  database then fill combobox items. The scenario is everytime i type text in to it, it clears the items then fill-in again. But the problem is, everytime it clears the items, the cursor points to the beginning of the inputbox.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the default behaviour of the ***ClearInternal*** method that is called inside the ObjectCollection class.

If you don't have a large amount of items you could easilly create an extension that you could use instead of the Clear method. Something like:

```
    public static void SafeClearItems(this ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        foreach (var item in new ArrayList(comboBox.Items))
        {
            comboBox.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

The default Clear method is better than this and it's using Array.Clear internally but you can't use that because you don't have access to the InnerList of the ObjectCollection where the items are actually stored. Otherwise I think you're stuck with your current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by implementing a little state management for your combobox using `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength`, e.g.

```
int _selectionStart = 0;
private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    this.comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    this.comboBox1.Focus();
    this.comboBox1.SelectionStart = _selectionStart;
    this.comboBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}

private void InputComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _selectionStart = this.InputComboBox.SelectionStart;
}
```

...this doesn't handle the mouse, so you'd need to hook up an additional event and capture the `_selectionStart` there as well.

Comment: My workaround at the moment is similar to that, but I was wondering why that's happening at all.  I was hoping to avoid that behavior altogether, but I can live with it if I must.